# How to get the screen on when usb attached (android 10)

Tags: java, android, monitor, usb-camera

I am working on an app and I am trying to find a way to wake the screen when I plug a usb camera to the phone while screen off on a android phone. I tried to monitor my usb connection but it didn't work, once the screen off, my app can no longer tell if a usb camera is connected.
Can somebody give me some ideas about how to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First: U need start the app when usb camera inserted

```html
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"/>
           </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
                android:resource="@xml/device_filter"/>

      </activity>
```

Second: keep screen on

```html
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

That work for me!